# 90's movie involving a super-soldier, a fear-smelling "monster", and a trapped man and woman

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember, sometime around 1995/96, watching a movie on satellite TV in the UK. I have no idea what it is called, but I would like to track it down. Pertinent details about the movie, as best as I can remember:

- Shown in the mid-90's, so probably made in the early 90's.
- The plot revolved around a super-soldier, a fear-smelling "monster", and a trapped man and woman. The super-soldier was "programmed" to have no fear and therefore gave off no pheromones, so the monster couldn't track/smell it.
- The best recollection I have is that the soldier bore a resemblance to *Halo*'s Master Chief, albeit with the lower part of his face visible.
- The super-soldier's objective was to get the man and woman to safety and to eliminate the monster.
- The three people and the monster were in a large, maze-like building.

Unfortunately, I have no idea who the actors/actress were or what studio made it. I couldn't even begin to guess at the title of the movie.

That's about the gist of it. I know it's a long shot, but if anyone has any kind of idea, I'd be glad to hear about it!

Comment: Do you recall what the super soldier or monster looked like?

Comment: Best recollection I have is the soldier bore a resemblance to Halo's Master Chief, albeit with lower part of face visible.  As for the monster, I honestly don't remember - my recollection of that is very vague and probably incorrect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like it is [Death Machine (1994)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109575/), [YouTube trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZ2DkxXbQ1Y)

Plot

> After a mad genius inventor of killer robots and cyborgs at Chaank
> Armaments Corp. kills execs, he unleashes his ultimate death machine
> on the new cute CEO firing him.

From https://satelliteshow.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/now-fear-this-death-machine/:

> In this case, it’s a **giant robot gorilla-dinosaur that smells fear**,
> and it’s up to your standard cyberpunk anti-heroic crew of
> mercenaries, salarymen, and corporate spies to do something about it

> After knocking the machine back, Raimi starts glitching again, and now
> when we get Warbeast POV, we see **fear pheromone signature** coming from
> Raimi

Our Cyborg:
[image]

The Monster:
[image]

Comment: Possibly, possibly not - I will take a look later and if it is, I'll mark this as the answer.  I'm not able to view YouTube videos right now.

Comment: I was just able to take a quick look at the trailer on my phone and I do believe you're correct and that is the movie I saw.  The exaggerated speed of the robot plus the POV screens are familiar so I would call this one solved.  Thank you @Yaroslav!  Marking as answered.

Comment: @PhilRigby you are welcome)

Comment: Crikey, i was at an vfx show and they were pushing this...and I think i thought it looked interesting at the time but it seemed to disappear. Not sure i could watch it now...

Answer (score 2):

Time frame doesn't quite line up but this could otherwise be [After Earth (2013)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1815862/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)

Where the monsters featured are receptive to human fear pheromones but one of the protagonists (Will Smith) shows that by overcoming his fear he becomes effectively invisible and can fight back.